# Capture and execute multiline code and incorporate result in raku

Tags: regex, replace, raku, capturing-group

This is a markdown document **example.md** I have:

````
## New language

Raku is a new language different from Perl.

## what does it offer
+ Object-oriented programming including generics, roles and multiple dispatch
+ Functional programming primitives, lazy and eager list evaluation, junctions, autothreading and hyperoperators (vector operators)
+ Parallelism, concurrency, and asynchrony including multi-core support
+ Definable grammars for pattern matching and generalized string processing
+ Optional and gradual typing



This code will be evaluated.


```{raku evaluate=TRUE}
4/5
```



Rakudo is a compiler for raku programming language. Install it and you're all set to run raku programs!

This code will be evaluated.

```{raku evaluate=TRUE}
say "this is promising";
say $*CWD;
```



This code will **not** be evaluated.


```{raku evaluate=FALSE}
say "Hello world";
```
````

which I want to convert into **example.md** as shown below with the code and output within it.

````
## New language

Raku is a new language different from Perl.

## what does it offer
+ Object-oriented programming including generics, roles and multiple dispatch
+ Functional programming primitives, lazy and eager list evaluation, junctions, autothreading and hyperoperators (vector operators)
+ Parallelism, concurrency, and asynchrony including multi-core support
+ Definable grammars for pattern matching and generalized string processing
+ Optional and gradual typing



This code will be evaluated.

Code:
```{raku evaluate=TRUE}
4/5
```

Output:
```
0.8
```

Rakudo is a compiler for raku programming language. Install it and you're all set to run raku programs!

This code will be evaluated.

Code:
```{raku evaluate=TRUE}
say "this is promising";
say $*CWD;
```

Output:
```
this is promising
"C:\Users\suman".IO
```

This code will **not** be evaluated.

Code:
```{raku evaluate=FALSE}
say "Hello world";
```
````

---

What I want to accomplish is:

- capture the code between `backticks{raku evaluate}` and `backticks`
- execute the code if evaluate is TRUE
- insert the code and output back into the document

---

What I tried to do:

1. Capture multiline code and evaluate expression

```
my $array= 'example.md'.IO.slurp;

#multiline capture code chunk and evaluate separately
if $array~~/\`\`\`\{raku (.*)\}(.*)\`\`\`/ {
    #the first capture $0 will be evaluate
    if $0~~"TRUE"{
        #execute second capture which is code chunk which is captured in $1
        }else {
       # don't execute code
        };
};
```

2. create a temp.p6 file and write code chunk $1 from above into it

```
my $fh="temp.p6".IO.spurt: $1;
```

3. execute the chunk if $0 is TRUE

```
my $output= q:x/raku temp.p6/ if $0==TRUE
```

4. integrate all this into final example.md while we create intermediate example_new.md

```
my $fh-out = open "example_new.md", :w; # Create a new file

# Print out next file, line by line
for "$file.tex".IO.lines -> $line {

    # write output of code to example_new.md

}
$fh-out.close;

# copy
my $io = IO::Path.new("example_new.md");
$io.copy("example.md");

# clean up
unlink("example.md");

# move
$io.rename("example.md");
```

I am stuck in the first step. Any help?

Comment: The two examples of `example.md` are exactly the same - were they supposed to be different?

Comment: @DeanTaylor Thanks for pointing out. I have fixed it.

Comment: @raiph Thank you. I want to clear some confusions. Original ``example.md`` file will have code chunks. Its won't have ``Code:`` and ``Output:``. It is present only in the output ``example.md`` file. If ``evaluate==TRUE`` in code chunk, then the code is executed. In final document whether code is executed or not, ``Code:`` will be present before chunk **and** if chunk executed, the output will have ``Output:`` before it. Could you please update the code accordingly at ``glot.io`` ? Currently its not throwing output as expected. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @SumanKhanal. Thanks for commenting. I've updated my answer and the code at glot.io. Lmk if that works for you. TIA.

Comment: Please reduce the examples to relevant parts.

Comment: @raiph Exactly what I wanted ! Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Code that accomplishes "What I want to accomplish"

You can [run this code against your data with glot.io](https://glot.io/snippets/fei4w96qrg).

````
use v6;

constant $ticks = '```';

my regex Search {
  $ticks '{raku evaluate=' $<evaluate>=(TRUE|FALSE) '}'
  $<code>=[<!before $ticks> .]*
  $ticks
}

sub Replace ($/) {
  "Code:\n" ~ $ticks ~ $<code> ~ $ticks ~
    ($<evaluate> eq 'TRUE'
      ?? "\n\n" ~ 'Output:' ~ "\n" ~ $ticks ~ "\n" ~ Evaluate($<code>) ~ $ticks
      !! '');
}

sub Evaluate ($code) {
  my $out; my $*OUT = $*OUT but role { method print (*@args) { $out ~= @args } }
  use MONKEY; my $eval-result = EVAL $code;
  $out // $eval-result ~ "\n"
}

spurt
  'example_new.md',
  slurp('example.md')
    .subst: &Search, &Replace, :g;
````

## Explanation

Starting at the bottom and then working upwards:

- [The `.subst` method](https://docs.raku.org/routine/subst) substitutes parts of its invocant string that need to be replaced and returns the revised string. `.subst`'s first argument is a matcher; it can be a string, or, as here, a regex -- `&Search`<sup>1</sup>. `.subst`'s second argument is a replacement; this can also be a string, or, as here, a `Callable` -- `&Replace`. If it's a `Callable` then `.subst` passes the match from the matcher as a [match object](https://docs.raku.org/type/Match)<sup>2</sup> as the first argument to the `Callable`. The `:g` adverb directs `.subst` to do the search/replace repeatedly for as many matches as there are in the invocant string.
- `slurp` generates a string in one go from a file. No need for `open`, using handles, `close`, etc. Its result in this case becomes the invocant of the `.subst` explained above.
- `spurt` does the opposite, generating a file in one go from a string, in this case the results of the `slurp(...).subst...` operation.
- The `Evaluate` routine generates a string that's the output from evaluating the string of code passed to it. To capture the result of evaluation it temporarily modifies [Raku's *STDOUT* variable `$*OUT`](https://docs.raku.org/language/variables#index-entry-%24%2AOUT), redirecting `print`s (and thus also `say`s etc.) to the internal variable `$out` before `EVAL`ing the code. If the `EVAL` results in anything being `print`d  to `$out` then that is returned; if not, then the result of the `EVAL` is returned (coerced to a string by the `~`). (A newline is appended in this second scenario but not the first because that is what's needed to get the correctly displayed result given how you've "specified" things by your example.)
- The `Replace` routine is passed a match object from a call of the `Code` regex. It reconstructs the code section (without the evaluate bit) using the `$<code>` capture. If the `$<evaluate>` capture is `'TRUE'` then it also appends a fresh `Output:` section using the `Evaluate` routine explained above to produce the code's output.
- The `Code` regex *matches* a code section. It *captures* the `TRUE` or `FALSE` setting from the evaluate directive into a capture named `$<evaluate>` and the code into a capture named `$<code>`.

## Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> To pass a routine (a regex is a routine) rather than call it, it must be written *with* a sigil (`&foo`), not without (`foo`).

<sup>2</sup> It does this even if the matcher was merely a string!

Comment: Great answer! Is there an easy modification of the code that allows the modified context (environment) between the code cells to be shared? E.g. assigned variables or loaded packages.

Comment: Please see this screenshot: https://imgur.com/5MyoD4a . For the last cell I get the message "Variable '$answer' is not declared".

Comment: I resolved these non-persistent state problems using a greatly reduced version for the class `Sandbox` of the package [Jupyter::Kernel](https://github.com/bduggan/p6-jupyter-kernel).

Comment: Hi @AntonAntonov. I ended up spending a couple hours playing around with various options. I introduced a new declarative `repl`. This rewrote each `Code:` section with that declarative as if it were entered into a REPL. Each line of code prefixed with `> `, then output, and with declarative effects retained. But I concluded you might want other stuff like proper handling of exceptions, and that what I was doing would quite likely better be done using the new `repl` function Liz has recently introduced. I'd love to see what you came up with if/when you're ready to share it.

Comment: Thank your efforts and update! Here is a GitHub repository with my solution: [Raku-Text-CodeProcessing](https://github.com/antononcube/Raku-Text-CodeProcessing).

Comment: "[...] using the new `repl` function Liz has recently introduced." -- I did not know about that new `repl` function. :) Is there a place I can find out more about it?

Comment: @AntonAntonov I found [this](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/pull/4325).

Answer (score 7):

There are two ways to execute the code and capture the output:

- You can write it to a tempfile and use `my $result = qqx{perl6 $filename}` to spawn a separate process
- You can execute the code in the same interpreter using `EVAL`, and use [IO::Capture::Simple](https://github.com/sergot/IO-Capture-Simple) to capture STDOUT:

````
my $re = regex {
    ^^ # logical newline
    '```{perl6 evaluate=' (TRUE|FALSE) '}'
    $<code>=(.*?)
    '```'
}

for $input.match(:global, $re) -> $match {
    if $match[0] eq 'TRUE' {
        use IO::Capture::Simple;
        my $result = capture_stdout {
            use MONKEY-SEE-NO-EVAL;
            EVAL $match<code>;
        }
        # use $result now
    }
}
````

Now you just need to switch from `match` to [`subst`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/subst#class_Str) and return the value from that block that you want to substitute in, and then you're done.

I hope this gives you some idea how to proceed.

Comment: Thank you. Your code worked fine but while evaluating ``4/5`` in one chunk, its throwing ``Any`` as output. What could be the reason its not 0.8?

Comment: The code I posted just looks at output to STDOUT, and `4/5` doesn't produce any output. Change it `say 4/5`. You could also check return value from EVAL, but my experience with IRC bots is that it's confusing if both output *and* return value are printed.

Answer (score -2):

You can try this regex:

````
```{perl6 evaluate=(?<evaluate>[^}]+)}\s+(?<code>[^`]+)
````

You will get three results from your sample text, each result contains two named groups, the first is `evaluate`, containing the flag and the second one `code`is the code.

Have a look at the regex-demo:
https://regex101.com/r/EsERkJ/1

Since I don't know perl, i can't help you with the implementation :(

Comment: Perl6 has a redesigned regex engine. (Which makes it easier to understand and write once you get used to it.) For example `(?<a>…)` is now written `$<a> = (…)`. (You can get back to the Perl5 style of regex using the `:P5` adverb.) Also every non-letter character and space must be escaped if you want it to match literally. Character classes are written differently as well. `"{perl6 evaluate=" $<evaluate> = (<-[}]>+) "}"` (A regex is treated as code with a different base syntax. They can have parameters and variables.)